# merge 2 tables with multiple conditions using pd.merge function

Tags: python

i would like to merge 2 tables with multiple conditions.
I'm seeking guidance on how to accomplish this using a Python script.
is there any way to merge it using pd.merge?

table1 left merge table2 where

1. table1.item = table2.item and table1.type = table2.category
2. if table1's type_c=1, match table1.entry_time > table2.update_time and (table1.entry_time-table2.update_time)<24hours
3. if table1's type_c=2, match table1.exit_time < table2.update_time and (table1.exit_time-table2.update_time)<24hours

below is the input and expected output

table1

| ITEM | CATEGORY | TYPE | ENTRY_TIME | EXIT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | 2023-08-30 08:00:00 | 2023-08-30 09:00:00 |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | 2023-09-01 10:00:00 | 2023-09-01 11:00:00 |
| ITEM1 | C | 2 | 2023-09-01 12:00:00 | 2023-09-01 13:00:00 |
| ITEM2 | B | 2 | 2023-09-02 16:00:00 | 2023-09-02 17:00:00 |
| ITEM3 | D | 1 | 2023-09-02 18:00:00 | 2023-09-02 19:00:00 |

table2

| ITEM | CATEGORY | REF_ID | BOOKING_C | UPDATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | A | 1111 | C | 2023-08-30 07:00:00 |
| ITEM1 | C | 2222 | R | 2023-09-01 14:00:00 |
| ITEM2 | B | 3333 | R | 2023-09-02 18:00:00 |
| ITEM3 | D | 4444 | C | 2023-09-02 17:00:00 |

expected result

| ITEM | CATEGORY | TYPE | ENTRY_TIME | EXIT_TIME | REF_ID | BOOKING_C | UPDATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | 2023-08-30 08:00:00 | 2023-08-30 09:00:00 | 1111 | C | 2023-08-30 07:00:00 |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | 2023-09-02 10:00:00 | 2023-09-02 11:00:00 |  |  |  |
| ITEM1 | C | 2 | 2023-09-01 12:00:00 | 2023-09-01 13:00:00 | 2222 | R | 2023-09-01 14:00:00 |
| ITEM2 | B | 2 | 2023-09-02 16:00:00 | 2023-09-02 17:00:00 | 3333 | R | 2023-09-02 18:00:00 |
| ITEM3 | D | 1 | 2023-09-02 18:00:00 | 2023-09-02 19:00:00 | 4444 |  |  |